# Issues with approval task starting no matter what a fields value is

Tags: designer-workflow, approval-process

So i tell the approval process to only start if a field is not equal to one of two values but no matter what, it starts anyway... can anyone help? attached is the WF...

[image]

Comment: Why are you using Or between first two conditions? Try using And condition.

Comment: It’s because the “reason for termination” field is a drop down with about 6 options but I only want it to start the task/approval process if those two options are chosen that’s why I’m using “or”.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want the approval process to start only when those to options are chosen for the "Reasonfor Termination" drop-down, why are using using the '*not equals*' qualifier? That means the approval process will start for any other choice made in that column. Seems like you want to use the '*equals*' qualifier for those conditions instead.

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong info I meant to put if it “doesn’t” equal one of those two start the task/approval process. So not equal would be correct. I tried the “wait” command so it would put “then” in from of start approval but I can’t get an or command with that so I’m confused on how to get it to work.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. If you temporarily remove the 'AND' condition and test it on one of the drop-down choices that you have set a 'not equals' condition to, does it still trigger the approval process?

Comment: removing the and statement did not work. I'm still fiddling with it, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

so i figured it out with the help of someone on a Microsoft form. i had to change my statements to equal and not not equal and type out other other options vs the two i wanted to use and it worked.